# How to permanently disable Bing translator on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, popups, bing

Chrome 59.0 64-bit on Windows 10. Recently there has been a change to the international version of Bing. The URL has been removed from `global.bing.com/?FORM=HPCNEN&setmkt=en-us&setlang=en-us` to `cn.bing.com/?FORM=HPCNEN&setmkt=en-us&setlang=en-us&intlF=` (`cn` denotes China, where I currently am). This is ok but what is really annoying is this: a popup window appears with Chinese translations of every word my cursor is on.

> [image]

It appears every time I visit Bing the translator will automatically be turned on (reportedly from `microsofttranslator.com`). I can temporarily turn it off by clicking a button on the search result page, but it will still be on the next time I use Bing.

Could anyone tell me if there is any way to **permanently** disable this popup translation window? If necessary, I would also like to know how to permanently ban `microsofttranslator.com` on my Chrome. Thanks.

PS: this is somewhat related to [this problem](https://superuser.com/q/468710/599490) which however was about IE. For Chrome I couldn't find a similar solution.

Comment: Are you able to determine if Chrome or Bing is offering the translation?

Comment: @Ramhound it must have been Bing, since Google is strictly blocked in China. Also, the translation only appears within Bing search pages.

Comment: Well you are using Chrome, so Google must not be entirely blocked, otherwise Chrome wouldn't work.  If the translation is being offered by Bing, then your Microsoft Account/[Bing](https://www.bing.com/account/general?ru=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2f%3fwlexpsignin%3d1&FORM=O2HV46&sh=0) settings should be adjusted

Comment: @Ramhound Chrome can work completely independent of Google. (Perhaps I would like to add that what I meant is all the *connections* to `google.com` are blocked, but not Chrome or other google softwares themselves). I didn't sign in to any Microsoft account when I use Bing, and I also couldn't find such Bing settings as related to this translation service.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by deleting the translator cookie.

The cookie will be set by the domain you are actually on, but will include a word like "translation" or "language" in the cookie name.  Mine was not obvious to find, it was called something like "TranslationMenu".

UPDATE: Since posting this I have noticed that bing now also sets other cookies that will need to also be deleted.

To delete specific cookies in Chrome you can:

- Go to the window and tab that has the Bing translation pop-ups
- Right click
- Click "Inspect"
- Click "Application" from top menu
- Click "Cookies" from the left
- Select the site name/URL
- Select the cookie
- Click the "x" next to the "Filter" box (on hover a tooltip will say delete cookie)

Answer (score 1):

It is because your country of origin is set to China in Bing settings (top right corner menu). I assume you are using a VPN. Unlike Google, Bing lets you declare your location, which is my favorite feature of Bing and the reason why I use it. You can open Bing settings and choose the United States, but then you will get a very annoying achievement counter on top. My personal preference is British Virgin Islands. Everything is clean and fully functional without any location-specific services.

Comment: "British Virgin Islands" makes no difference now. I use a browser extension"Click to Remove Element" to hide the button and icon